# XmlReader - How to update progress bar

Tags: c#, xml, progress-bar, large-files

I'm reading really large XML files (more than 6GB of data) using **XmlReader** to speedup everything and works really well.

I'm doing this operation in another thread, (*not with Background Worker*) and I can't figure out how to update the progress bar, because XmlReader doesn't haves some sort of "current position, consumed bytes" or something like that who can help me to create an average calculation about the progress.

I tried to use XmlReader along with StreamReader to can count the bytes of every line, and after that updating the progress bar based on the **consumed bytes / the file length * 100**, but the program at some point give me an error like

> Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 109, position 27.'

when using the StreamReader `Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(ReadLine())`.

What is a good method to achieve this?
I've searched on google and found some ways to achieve this, but without using XmlReader, and I can't not use XmlReader.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at the position of the underlying stream:

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead("somePath"))
{
    using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(fileStream))
    {
        long lastPosition = 0;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (lastPosition != fileStream.Position)
            {
                lastPosition = fileStream.Position;

                Console.WriteLine($"Read {lastPosition} from {fileStream.Length} ({100.0 * lastPosition / fileStream.Length}%)");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that this will give you different outputs depending on the underlying stream that you use. On my system, the reader reads blocks of 4KB.

Comment: @MutuA. It will read in blocks, that varies according to your system, mine is 4096. This will be your resolution. So, it will not increase for every node read, but every 8kB read. Look ahead in your loop and you'll see it increases, you are probably only looking the first few nodes, which all are inside the first 8kB

Comment: @Magnetron Thank you, now is much clear. Yes I've tested it only with a few nodes...